# better way to implemet 2d platformer rooms system in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, architecture, game-development

I'm currently making a 2d platformer game with unity. I'm going to build game world with rooms (like in Hollow Knight and many other metroidvania games). So, my first idea is to have each room as a separate prefab with virtual camera and exits linked to other rooms on scene. And to have several scenes (smth like each scene contains a set of "thematic" rooms).

I have another idea but i'm not sure if it gonna work properly in terms of perfomance. The idea is simple - to have single game scene and instantiate\destroy game rooms dynamically and seamless. So the game will have current room and all adjacent rooms loaded (with some depth maybe, i.e. all adjacent rooms with depth R), when player changes room - some new rooms are instanciated and others destroyed. This feels like a good idea, cause after creating dynamic room system you can just concentrate on creating and linking rooms. But i'm afraid it can lead to some perfomance problems (i.e. game freezes when player moves from one room to another if there is a big enough room nearby). And i guess there can be a lot more unexpected problems.

So it's kind of open-type question. What do you think about this "dynamic" approach? Is it worth trying? If you have expirience building similar games, what design approach did you use?

Answer (score 1):

Typically, creating and destroying objects in-game is a no due to performance issues.
From my high school game dev teacher, a better way to do it is to preload everything outside the camera, and just move needed resources into view as needed for a randomly generated scene.
If you're looking for a static scene, I would just preload everything that I need for that specific scene.